# overwrite or extend a template in an Acceleo template

Tags: eclipse, templates, extend, overwrite, acceleo

I have 3 template for example:-

```
main, genA, genB
```

The `genB` module is a specification for `genA` and supposed to overwrite one template `bar`. The problem is, that if you call the overwritten template within genA it is not the template specified in `genB.`

Here are the simplified templates:-

main:-

```
[module main('http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML')]

[import genB /]

[template public generateElement(aClass : Class)]
[comment @main/]
[foo() /][bar() /]
[/template]
```

genA:-

```
[module generateA('http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML') extends genB]

[template public foo()]
[bar() /]
[/template]

[template public bar()]
barA
[/template]
```

genB:-

```
[module generateB('http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML') extends genA]

[template public bar() overrides bar]
barB
[/template]
```

the output is `barAbarB` so the call within `genA` is not overwritten. This behavior is mentioned in the [docs](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.acceleo.doc%2Fpages%2Freference%2Flanguage.html#template). What would be the suggested way to overwrite the template ?

Answer (score 0):

"Static overriding feels like overriding in an object oriented language like Java but it is different because modules are not objects, they are more similar to namespaces"
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ#How_does_the_overriding_system_works_in_Acceleo_.3F
You should try to use dynamic overriding.